# RSpec send_file testing with check of Content-Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sendfile

I have a Rails Controller that send a file with different Content-Type

Example for Exel-File, the controller set Content-Type = `"application/excel"`

and here is the RSpec test:

```
describe "GET getfile" do
  it "Excel File" do
    controller.stub(:render)
    controller.should_receive(:send_file)
    get :getfile, :name => 'test+xls'
    controller.response.header.should == '???'
  end
end
```

The answer from the test is:

```
1) ExportController GET getfile Excel File
   Failure/Error: controller.response.header.should == ''
     expected: ""
          got: {"Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"} (using ==)
     Diff:
     @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
     -""
     +"Content-Type" => "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: `controller.stub(:render)`, `controller.should_receive(:send_file)`. 
These lines change controller methods to return nil when called. You cannot check that method is called and it's return value in a single test with rspec matchers. Split tests or use some other gem for expectations.
And it would be great to see controller code too if it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing (or already using) the thoughtbot shoulda gem, paperclip hooks into it

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/shoulda_macros/paperclip.rb

and has an s3 upload method.